# Append to each dictionary within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary objects:

```
[{u'ID': 46757,
  u'currentenddate': u'09/30/2016',
  u'name': u'Project A',
  u'projstartdate': u'05/01/2016'},
 {u'ID': 46625,
  u'currentenddate': u'07/15/2016',
  u'name': u'Project B',
  u'projstartdate': u'05/02/2016'},
 {u'ID': 47100,
  u'currentenddate': u'08/02/2016',
  u'name': u'Project C',
  u'projstartdate': u'06/01/2016'}]
```

and I would like to append to ALL dictionary items a new field `client_id`, resulting in:

```
[{u'ID': 46757,
  u'currentenddate': u'09/30/2016',
  u'name': u'Project A',
  u'projstartdate': u'05/01/2016'},
  u'client_id': u'12398'},
 {u'ID': 46625,
  u'currentenddate': u'07/15/2016',
  u'name': u'Project B',
  u'projstartdate': u'05/02/2016'},
  u'client_id': u'12398'},
 {u'ID': 47100,
  u'currentenddate': u'08/02/2016',
  u'name': u'Project C',
  u'projstartdate': u'06/01/2016'}
  u'client_id': u'12398'}]
```

`client_id` will remain the same for all dictionary items.  I know I can achieve the outcome using a `for` loop coupled with `dict['client_id'] = id` but the code is no longer vectorized.  Is there a pythonic way to append to each dict item within the list?

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the lively conversation about list comprehensions versus `for` loops.  I'll test both methods and use the faster of the two for my situation.  Also, going forward, I'll explicitly define what I mean by 'vectorized' and 'pythonic' in my questions, so we're all on the same page (thanks, @Adam Smith).

Comment: What exactly is the concern with vectorization here? There's really no performance hit to just using a `for` loop with `update`...

Comment: If there's no hit to performance, then I'll use the `for` loop.  Whenever I use `for` loops with `pandas`, there's a serious performance hit, and I assumed that was also the case for a `list`.  I'll do some research on why performance is not affected using `for` on lists.

Comment: That's because `pandas` has compiled and optimized logic to process these things. If you're dealing with purely Python constructs, you should absolutely make the zero-to-minimal tradeoff in legibility of just using a `for` loop.

Comment: Why not to use `for` loop when it provides you the most efficient way. I do not know any such in-built python function to achieve this. In case if there is any, internally it will iterating over your list

Comment: Added an answer to achieve it using without `for` loop

Comment: Depends on what you mean by _pythonic_. There are 4 solutions (I'm excluding the one that was deleted) that use _Python_ features, but some of them perform additional calculations/conversions that might run slower than the classic `for` loop. As I mentioned in a comment, list comprehensions seem to be ~2 times faster(_Python2.7.10_ on _Win_) than classic iteration (the example is adding 1 to each element from a list of _int_ s).

Comment: @CristiFati list comps aren't faster than `for` loops. If you show me your test code I'll show you your misstep.

Comment: Voting to close this as "Too Broad." The correct answer is "Use a `for` loop," but the *specific* question of "How do I do this as a vectorized function" is *massively* too broad to answer here.

Comment: @Adam Smith I had large list of _int_ s; generated another one where each element is the correspondent element + 1. One way is via list comprehensions, the other is creating the new list, iterating over the existing one and appending each element + 1. But I'll definitely take a deeper look into this tomorrow, when I'll also have access to _Python_ source code.

Comment: the `for` loop there is slower because it has to do a `__getitem__` per list element, while the list comprehension doesn't have to do any lookup at all (it's building the list as it goes along).

Comment: it wouldn't surprise me if building a new list took longer as a `for` loop if you have a deterministic input, since the list comp can pre-allocate the list and not have to grow it so much. However in a case like this you'll see [that it's considerably slower](http://pastebin.com/22p0HjEd)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could do the trick.

```
result = [dict(data, client_id='') for data in list_of_dicts]
```

Comment: this just creates a new copy of each dict in memory. It's still iterating just like a `for` loop.

Comment: Can't one argue that list comprehensions are faster than a `for` loop?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's no longer the case. I know I've seen talk of it, but I think it's mostly pre-2.7 (if not earlier).

Comment: It is still using `for` loop.

Comment: Just tested(_Python2.7.10_ on _Win_)....it seems that list comprehension is ~2 times faster than "manually" iterating over each element.

Comment: @CristiFati I just tested with Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, and in both cases a plain old for loop was 2-3 times faster than creating a new dict with a comprehension.

Comment: Yes, @tobias_k, but I guess that's just because with the `for` loop you altered the existing list, while list comprehension generates another list (and maybe all the dicts). My test case was a simpler one (adding 1 to each element (_int_)), but that case doesn't quite apply here.

Answer (score -1):

A **Python 3.5** solution showcasing the new dict *unpacking*.

```
[{**dict_element, **{u'client_id':u'12398'}} for dict_element in your_list]
```

Check [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

**Demo**

```
>>> your_list = [{u'ID': 46757,
...   u'currentenddate': u'09/30/2016',
...   u'name': u'Project A',
...   u'projstartdate': u'05/01/2016'},
...  {u'ID': 46625,
...   u'currentenddate': u'07/15/2016',
...   u'name': u'Project B',
...   u'projstartdate': u'05/02/2016'},
...  {u'ID': 47100,
...   u'currentenddate': u'08/02/2016',
...   u'name': u'Project C',
...   u'projstartdate': u'06/01/2016'}]
>>> 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([{**dict_element, **{u'client_id':u'12398'}} for dict_element in your_list])
[{'ID': 46757,
  'client_id': '12398',
  'currentenddate': '09/30/2016',
  'name': 'Project A',
  'projstartdate': '05/01/2016'},
 {'ID': 46625,
  'client_id': '12398',
  'currentenddate': '07/15/2016',
  'name': 'Project B',
  'projstartdate': '05/02/2016'},
 {'ID': 47100,
  'client_id': '12398',
  'currentenddate': '08/02/2016',
  'name': 'Project C',
  'projstartdate': '06/01/2016'}]
```

Comment: functionally identical to mic4ael's answer.

Comment: its that bad? .. a way to show the new dict unpacking